# Limited-access user permission lockdown mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, features

I need to find out what the exact impact is to the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature if I deactivate the Limited-access user permission lockdown mode feature.  Microsoft says that it will have a negative impact, but that does not tell me very much and I need both set this way:  Limited-access user permission lockdown mode - Not Active; SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure - Active.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I think OneDrive sites are setup this way by default.

Answer (score 1):

I talked with MS and they said that you can deactivate the Limited-access user permission lockdown mode feature, while the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature if Active.  Had them send me an email stating that fact, so if anything comes up from doing that I have proof they stated this to me.  Not sure it will help, but can't hurt.

Comment: So after a time, were there any issues having "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode - Not Active; SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure - Active"?